# UiAlertView or UiAlertController to display only once in Swift

Tags: swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

How can I get my `UiAlertController` or `UIAlertView` to display only once in Swift?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let nameIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("name") as? String {
        self.name.text = defaults.objectForKey("name") as String
    }

    if let phoneIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("phone") as? String {
        self.phone.text = defaults.objectForKey("phone") as String
    }

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "WE STRIVES TO PROVIDE ACCURATE, UP-TO-DATE INFORMATION ON THIS APPS.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Disagree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only once"? You are actually putting the code into the `viewDidLoad ` method, which means the alert will be shown each time the view will be loaded up. Consider executing the code only when a button is pressed.

Comment: I wanted the uialertview to load up automatically once the page is loaded, but only display once.  I didn't want the uialertview to display when pressing a button.  Basically, when loading the app, the first thing the user see is the disclaimer.  Once the ok button is press, the disclaimer will never appear again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a global `Bool` variable just under `import` commands:

```
var justOnce:Bool = true
```

You should use it this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let nameIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("name") as? String {
        name.text = defaults.objectForKey("name") as String
    }

    if let phoneIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("phone") as? String {
         phone.text = defaults.objectForKey("phone") as String
    }

    if justOnce {
       var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "WE STRIVES TO PROVIDE ACCURATE, UP-TO-DATE INFORMATION ON THIS APPS.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Disagree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        justOnce = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a Complier Error under the justOnce = false.

Comment: Swift Error:  Cannot assign to 'let' value 'just Once'

Comment: if justOnce == true is redundant. Why don't you just write if justOnce {...}

Comment: @Coder: use `var` instead of `let`. My bad. I edited my answer.

Comment: You can't do that (`justOnce == false`). You must assign a value. You shouldn't compare it. What error are you getting with my actual code?

Comment: you don't nee to use == true or == false

Comment: if justOnce {...}   or  if !justOnce {...}

Comment: self.presentViewController ? just presentViewController

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the code in this thread so as to allow the user to **"Do Not Show This Message Again"**. Essentially, shows the alert and gives the user the ability to disable the alert in future.

Code as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

....

let AlertOnce = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if(!AlertOnce.boolForKey("oneTimeAlert")){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Note:", message: "Some message to be displayed on screen to the user", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let DoNotShowAgainAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Do Not Show Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        AlertOnce.setBool(true , forKey: "oneTimeAlert")
        AlertOnce.synchronize()

        }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        alert.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(DoNotShowAgainAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

....

}
```

I put it in the `viewDidLoad()` section of my relevant UIViewController so it loads on initial view/call of the page.

Hope this helps someone with a similar need.

Comments and modifications most welcome ;)

**** UPDATE ****

I got an error on testing -

> "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged"

I found this excellent post that helped me resolve the issue : http://timdietrich.me/blog/swift-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discouraged/

Quoting the article:

> Notice that I was trying to present the UIAlertController in the
>   class's viewDidLoad function. And that's the problem. You see, at that
>   point, the view has loaded, but it hasn't appeared yet. I believe
>   that's why the warning is referring to a "detached view controller."
>
> The solution that I found is to present the view controller not in the
>   viewDidLoad function, but instead in the viewDidAppear function. At
>   that point the view has loaded and is being displayed.

So I updated my code and moved the relevant block to the `viewDidAppear` section and all is well. NO errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Just add this code in AppDelegate.swift file it will work perfectly for one time alertview

=======

`let AlertOnce = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()                if(!changeAlert.boolForKey("oneTimeAlert")){                                              var alert = UIAlertView()                                                            alert.title = "Welcome"                                                                                     alert.message = "welcome message"                                                     alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")                                                       alert.delegate = self                                                                alert.show()                                                                                         AlertOnce.setBool(true , forKey: "oneTimeAlert")                                     AlertOnce.synchronize()}`